# Why won't my jbutton add itself again?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint

I'm making a Blackjack game. Everything is done and i wanted to make a reset button to start the game over. I removeAll() in the ActionListener, but when Board() starts again it doesn't add either JButton draw or fold. Please help
P.S. the Cards() constructor is all of my card image files.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    Cards deck=new Cards();

    static ArrayList<BufferedImage> pcards=new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
    static ArrayList<BufferedImage> ccards=new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
    static BufferedImage back;

    static int w=1280/2;
    static int h=760/2;

    static ArrayList<String> p=new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> com=new ArrayList<String>();

    static Boolean last=true;
    static String end="";

    public Board()
    {
        setLayout(null);

        Color green=new Color(00,55,00);
        setBackground(green);

        try 
        {     
            String c="Deck\\"+deck.draw();
            p.add(c);           
            pcards.add(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(c)));
            c="Deck\\"+deck.draw();
            p.add(c);
            pcards.add(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(c)));
            c="Deck\\"+deck.draw();
            com.add(c);
            ccards.add(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(c)));
            c="Deck\\"+deck.draw();
            com.add(c);
            ccards.add(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(c)));

            back=(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("Deck\\b1fv.GIF")));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
          //Not handled. 
        }
        int cp=Integer.parseInt(Score(com));
        while(cp<17)
        {
            try
            {
                String c="Deck\\"+deck.draw();
                com.add(c);
                ccards.add(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(c)));
            }

            catch (IOException e) 
            { 
             //Not handled. 
            }
            cp=Integer.parseInt(Score(com));
        }

        JButton draw=new JButton("Draw");
        draw.setBounds(w-120,h-30,90,40);
        draw.setFont(new Font("Arabic", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        draw.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
            {
                int pp=Integer.parseInt(Score(p));      
            if(pp>21||end.length()>0)
            {
                last=false;
                repaint();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    String c="Deck\\"+deck.draw();
                    p.add(c);           
                    pcards.add(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(c)));
                    repaint();
            }
                catch (IOException e) 
                { 
                //Not handled. 
                }
            }}
        });
        add(draw);


        JButton fold=new JButton("Fold");
        fold.setBounds(w+40,h-30,90,40);
        fold.setFont(new Font("Arabic", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        fold.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
            {
                int pp=Integer.parseInt(Score(p));  
                int cp=Integer.parseInt(Score(com));
                end=End(pp,cp);
                last=false;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        add(fold);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        g.setFont(new Font("Arabic", Font.PLAIN, 50));
        g.setColor(Color.black);

        int pp=Integer.parseInt(Score(p));  
        int cp=Integer.parseInt(Score(com));
        if(pp>21)
        {
            end=End(pp,cp);
            last=false;
        }
        int i=0;
        for(BufferedImage temp:pcards)
        {
            g.drawImage(temp, (w-120)+i, (h+(h/2))-80,100,170, null);
            i+=60;
        }
        i=0;
        if(last)
        {
            for(BufferedImage temp:ccards)
            {
                g.drawImage(back, (w-120)+i, (h-(h/2))-100,100,170, null);
                i+=60;
            }
            g.drawString("Score:",(w-(w/2))-90,h-40);
            g.drawString("???", (w-(w/2))-70, h+40);
        }
        else
        {
            for(BufferedImage temp:ccards)
            {
                g.drawImage(temp, (w-120)+i, (h-(h/2))-100,100,170, null);
                i+=60;
            }
            g.drawString("Score:",w-(w/2)-90,h-40);
            g.drawString(Score(com), (w-(w/2))-50, h+40);
        }   
        g.drawString("Score:",w+(w/2)-50,h-40);
        g.drawString(Score(p), (w+(w/2)), h+40);

        int j=end.length();
        g.setFont(new Font("Arabic", Font.PLAIN, 70));
        Color l=new Color(66,153,204);
        g.setColor(l);
        g.drawString(end,(w-(j*20))+20,h-(h/2));

        if(end.length()>0)
        {
            g.setFont(new Font("Arabic", Font.PLAIN, 30));
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString("Play Again?",(w-(w/2))-160,h+(h/2));

            JButton reset=new JButton("Yes");
            reset.setBounds((w-(w/2))-120,(h+(h/2))+30,90,40);
            reset.setFont(new Font("Arabic", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    last=true;
                    end="";
                    pcards.clear();ccards.clear();p.clear();com.clear();
                    repaint();
                    removeAll();
                    new Board();

                }
            });
            add(reset);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    }

    public static String End(int x,int y)
    {
        if(x>21 && y<=21)
            end="You Busted! Computer Won!";
        else if(x<=21 && y>21)
            end="You Won! Computer Busted!";
        else if(x>21 && y>21)
            end="Both Busted! Draw!";
        else if(x>y)
            end="You Win!";
        else if(x<y)                
            end="You Lost!";
        else
            end="You and Computer Tied! Draw!";
        return end;
    }

    public static String Score(ArrayList<String> x)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0; i<x.size(); i++)
        {
            String z=x.get(i);
            if(z.charAt(6)=='2')
                sum+=2;
            if(z.charAt(6)=='3')
                sum+=3;
            if(z.charAt(6)=='4')
                sum+=4;
            if(z.charAt(6)=='5')
                sum+=5;
            if(z.charAt(6)=='6')
                sum+=6;
            if(z.charAt(6)=='7')
                sum+=7;
            if(z.charAt(6)=='8')
                sum+=8;
            if(z.charAt(6)=='9')
                sum+=9;
            if(z.charAt(6)=='1')
                sum+=10;
            if(z.charAt(6)=='j')
                sum+=10;
            if(z.charAt(6)=='q')
                sum+=10;
            if(z.charAt(6)=='k')
                sum+=10;
            if(z.charAt(6)=='a')
            {
                if(sum<=10)
                    sum+=11;
                else
                    sum+=1;
            }                           
        }
        String score=""+sum;
        return score;   
    }
}
public class BlackJack extends JFrame
{
    public BlackJack()
    {
        add(new Board());       
        System.out.println("Starting BlackJack...");
        setTitle("Blackjack");
        setSize(getToolkit().getScreenSize().width, getToolkit().getScreenSize().height-40);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        new BlackJack();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Change every occurrence of `catch (IOException e) 
            { 
             //Not handled.` to `catch (IOException e) 
            { 
             e.printStackTrace();` 2) It is most likely that by the timw this app. reaches the end user, those resources will not be available as `File` objects and thereby must be accessed by `URL`. 3) In any case the `\\` separator used in the file name is wrong for 2/3 of the major platforms on which J2SE runs.

Answer (score 2):

Question: You create a new Board object but what do you add it to?

Answer: Nothing, and so there is no way for it to display itself.

Having said that, a better solution is not to create a new Board object but rather is usually to figure out how to reset your current Board to its initial state.

Comment: +1, for resetting the state. There should be no need to add/remove components.

Comment: Make a reset method that makes gives it the initial status you want, and then call it on the constructor and also call it on reset.

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT EVER modify the state of your UI from any `paint` method. This will only cause a new repaint request to be raised over and over and over .... Until it consumes your CPU (turns into a singularity and sucks your PC into oblivion...)

Also, while we're at it, you should be overriding `paintComponent` and not `paint`.  Paint is responsible for painting all the child components, which you are now painting over.  This is going to cause you no end of misery in the long run.

Comment: So change paint method to paintComponent? I'm sorry i'm very new at this

Comment: `paintComponent` is the preferred/recommend method for performing custom painting, yes, it would be more appropriate, unless you have a VERY good reason to do so (which doesn't happen often).  Check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use static variables, there is no need to do this.
2. Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.
3. Don't override the paint() method. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method.
4. Don't add/remove components in any painting method.

Answer (score 1):

I Agree with "camickr"… Since the variables are `static`, they aren't getting re-initiated, they are staying at their previous settings and preferences. I suggest this...

```
public class BlackJack
{
    public static JFrame frame;

    public BlackJack()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("BlackJack");

        add(new Board());       
        System.out.println("Starting BlackJack...");
        setSize(getToolkit().getScreenSize().width, getToolkit().getScreenSize().height-40);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        new BlackJack();
    }
}
```

Make the BlackJack JFrame `static` So that you can remove the board from it then add a new one… Add this into what the User does to reset it. Like the `JButton`'s `ActionListener` or if the user clicks a letter on the keyboard like 'R', then Reset… Like So…

```
public void reset()
{
    frame.remove(this);
    frame.add(new Board());
}
```

If this doesn't answer you're question, please let me know. If this doesn't seem reasonable to anyone, help me figure it out. :D